# Ng-Zorro select not showing selected items with NgModel

Tags: html, json, angular, multi-select, ng-zorro-antd

I am using Ng-Zorro's multiple select, which is in a drawer. When opening the drawer, I give the select element a list of options and a list of items that are already chosen. The list of options to pick from works fine, but the already selected items do not show. This can be seen here as well: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pusp9u)

The code:

```
<nz-select [(ngModel)]="selectedAttributes"
                 [nzMaxTagCount]="3"
                 [nzMaxTagPlaceholder]="attributeTagPlaceHolder"
                 nzMode="multiple"
                 name="changeAttributes"
                 id ="changeAttributes"
                 nzPlaceHolder="Please select">
    <nz-option *ngFor="let attribute of allAttributes" [nzLabel]="attribute.name" [nzValue]="attribute"></nz-option>
 </nz-select>
 <ng-template #attributeTagPlaceHolder let-selectedList> "and " {{ selectedList.length }} " more items" </ng-template>
```

where the allAttributes list is formatted like this:

```
allAttributes= [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mask"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Intensive"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Family"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Isolation"
}
```

];

and where the selectedAttributes is one or more of the items in the allAttributes list:

```
selectedAttributes= [{"id": 1,"name": "Mask"}];
```

No matter how I create or format the selected attributes list (it can be straight from the allAttributes list), the placeholder cannot be seen and the select is empty, plus when picking all options, the nzMaxTagPlaceholder shows there is an extra item picked.

Can anyone show me the way to set the selected items dynamically?

Comment: Your stackblitz application is not working. And if you can share an editable one it would be better.

Comment: Fixed stackblitz link. :)

Comment: See my answer applied to your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pusp9u-mdt5wy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sth like below.

```
selectedAttributes = [this.allAttributes[0]];
```

Since

```
{"id": 1,"name": "Hapnikumask"}
```

is a complex object its equality will be checked by references. So you are defining a new object as selected it will be different from the source object.

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a small thing but I didn't think about it and have been trying to fix this for so long.

Answer (score 2):

use compareFn in your nz-select like this.

```
<nz-select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  [compareWith]="compareFn"
  (ngModelChange)="log($event)"
  nzAllowClear
  nzPlaceHolder="Choose"
>
```

in typescript file:-

```
compareFn = (o1: any, o2: any): boolean => (o1 && o2 ? o1.id === o2.id : o1 === o2);
```

Comment: You saved my day. I think it's because nz-select doesn't know how to find the selected item in the list of options so you need to tell it.